# regex from scraped data using lookaround not working

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to figure out why one of my regex commands works but the other doesn't. Here's a sample of two strings it would pull from. There is consistency in the new line garbage which resulted from the scrape so I used that to my advantage as best I could:

```
"\n\tMenghe a'Nyam\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 215lb (196cm, 
97kg) \n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: Canisius\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"

"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Guard\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb (206cm, 
102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  
School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

My goal is to pull desired data from this such as position (Forward, Guard respectively) and most importantly, height (6-5, 6-9, respectively). I had success pulling the position with the following:

```
test <- df %>%
  mutate(position = str_extract(player, "(?<=Position:\n  \n  ).*?(?=\n\n\n\n  \\d-\\d)"))
```

But when I follow a similar lookaround to add another col for height, it returns NA:

```
test <- df %>%
  mutate(position = str_extract(player, "(?<=Position:\n  \n  ).*?(?=\n\n\n\n  \\d-\\d)")) %>%
  mutate(height = str_extract(player, "(?<=\\w+\n\n\n\n  ).*?(?=, \\d{3}lb)"))
```

Here is a sample of the result from above call on the first 3 rows of my df if it's helpful:

```
structure(list(player = c("\n\tMenghe a'Nyam\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 215lb (196cm, 97kg) \n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: Canisius\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb (206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tKarl Aaker\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 210lb (196cm, 95kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Reno, NV\n\n\n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: Portland\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  
), position = c("Forward", "Forward", "Forward"), height = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove `+` after `\w` since ICU regex engine does not support unlimited length string matching patterns inside lookbehinds, and use `\s` to match any whitespaces:

```
test <- df %>%
  mutate(position = str_extract(player, "(?<=Position:\n  \n  ).*?(?=\n\n\n\n  \\d-\\d)")) %>%
  mutate(height = str_extract(player, "(?<=\\w\n{4}\\s{2}).*?(?=,\\s+\\d{3}lb)"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LVS3Pf/2)

**Details**

- `(?<=\w\n{4}\s{2})` - immediately before the match, there should be a word char, then 4 newline chars and then any 2 whitespace chars
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=,\s+\d{3}lb)` - immediately after the match, there should be a comma, one or more whitespace chars, 3 digits and `lb` substring.

Comment: Wiktor as always, thank you! I know I'm a regex newbie but you continue to help me understand some new nuance each time you generously provide such detailed and thoughtful responses. Hopefully my question phrasing is at least improving! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `stringr` and `tidyr`. First I remove all `\n` and  `\t` because they really annoy me.

```r
test <- df %>%
  mutate(player = str_replace_all(player, "\n|\r|\t", ""),
         position = str_extract(player, "(?<=Position:).+(?=\\s\\d-\\d)"),
         height = str_extract(player, "\\d-\\d?(?=,\\s\\d{3}lb)"))
```

We can do all mutations in on step. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: this was close - but enough for me to learn and improve. thanks so much!

Comment: you're still a hero in my eyes